Resending confirmation email results in "A failure has occurred" error
I'm encountering an error while trying to resend a confirmation email in my ASP.NET Core application. The error message I'm receiving is:
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.6.1",
  "title": "A failure has occurred.",
  "status": 500,
  "traceId": "00-c71e0f8c6ac4b719b1fe02064c9d75e3-598ddc56be83a968-00",
  "errorCodes": "customValue"
}

I'm using MediatR for handling requests and responses. Here's the relevant code snippet for the ResendEmailConfirmationAsync method in my AuthenticationController:
[HttpGet("resend-confirmation-email")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResendConfirmationEmailAsync([FromQuery]ConfirmEmailRequest request)
{
    var resendConfirmationResult = await _mediatr.Send(_mapper.Map<ConfirmEmailCommand>(request));

    return resendConfirmationResult.Match(
        success => Ok("Confirmation email resent successfully"),
        errors => Problem(errors));
}

And here's the corresponding handler for the ResendEmailConfirmationCommand:
public record ResendEmailConfirmationCommand(string Email, string BaseUrl)
    : IRequest<ErrorOr<Success>>;

public class ResendEmailConfirmationCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<ResendEmailConfirmationCommand, ErrorOr<Success>>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IUserAuthenticationService _userAuthenticationService;
    private readonly EmailService _emailService;

    public ResendEmailConfirmationCommandHandler(IUserRepository userRepository, 
        EmailService emailService, IUserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationService)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _emailService = emailService;
        _userAuthenticationService = userAuthenticationService;
    }

    public async Task<ErrorOr<Success>> Handle(ResendEmailConfirmationCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var userOrError = await _userRepository.GetByEmailAsync(request.Email);
        if (userOrError.IsError)
        {
            return userOrError.Errors;
        }

        var user = userOrError.Value;
        if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            var emailToken = await _userAuthenticationService.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            string? userName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
                {
                    userName = user.Email;
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
                {
                    userName = user.FirstName;
                }
                else
                {
                    userName = user.LastName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                userName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
            }

            var emailResult = await _emailService.SendEmailConfirmationEmailAsync(user.Id, user.Email!, emailToken, 
                request.BaseUrl, userName!);
            return emailResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return Error.Failure("Email already confirmed.");
        }
    }
}

When I debugged the code, I received the following error:
ErrorOr { IsError = True, Errors = System.Collections.Generic.List1[ErrorOr.Error], ErrorsOrEmptyList = System.Collections.Generic.List1[ErrorOr.Error], Value = , FirstError = Error { Code = User email is not confirmed! Reasons: Invalid token., Description = A failure has occurred., Type = Failure, NumericType = 0, Metadata = } }
It seems like there's an issue with the token or email confirmation process. How can I resolve this error and successfully resend the confirmation email? Thank you for your help!

You seem to be sending a ConfirmEmailCommand but the handler you've added in your question expects a ResendEmailConfirmationCommand. Are you sure it's reaching the correct handler?
